# Garage switch and remotes will not work

Tags: doors, garage

My garage switch on the wall and my remotes will not open the garage.I unplugged the opener and then everything started back working. An hour later it all stopped again. I unpluged it again and they started back for a little while.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What's the make and model of the opener? Was everything working, and then this happened? What changed?

Comment: Thanks, it's an Overhead door Legacy 1/3 hp. Model 496CD/B.. A little over a month ago I replaced the little white plastic inner drive piece. Wife went to open it with the wall switch and nothing. I got home it worked with my remote. I figured the wall switch was bad till the remotes did not work soon after. When I unpluged it everything works for a little bit then stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a defect in the garage opener, probably in the receiver electronics.  A device like this should not stop working without warning and restart again on a "reboot".

I would look into whether you can replace the receiver without replacing the entire device.